# Proving that product of functions is not monotonic

Tags: calculus

Given two function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which is strictly monotonic increasing and $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which is strictly monotonic decreasing I need to prove that $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ is not monotonic.

I started my proof with assuming that $h(x)$ is strictly monotonic increasing so for every $x_1 < x_2$ I know that $h(x_1) < h(x_2)$ which means that $f(x_1)g(x_1) < f(x_2)g(x_2)$ but I'm stuck here and don't how to continue. I know that $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$ and $g(x_1) > g(x_2)$ but I don't know how to connect between them.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. Consider $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=-e^x$. Then $(fg)(x)=-e^{2x}$ is strictly decreasing.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are misunderstanding the question. Most likely, it says something along the lines of "Prove or disprove: If $f,g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ with $f$ monotonic increasing and $g$ monotonic decreasing, then $h=fg$ is monotonic."

In order to disprove, you aren't supposed to show that such a product is **never** monotonic (in fact, this is impossible, as sometimes such products *are* monotonic). You are just supposed to find one that isn't.

There's a ***really*** basic nonconstant increasing function $f(x)$, with $g(x)=-f(x)$, that make for a nice counterexample.

Comment: Really, really basic.

Comment: but it's not what I need to prove/disprove. this counterexample just shows what the question requests to prove: that product of two strictly increasing and decreasing function is not monotonic.

for example $f(x) = x$ (strictly increasing) and $g(x) = -x$ (strictly decreasing) then $(fg)(x) = -x^2$ which not monotonic but that what i need to disprove (or prove for each function).

but it seems like i can use $f(x) = e^{x}$ and $g(x) = -e^{x}$ and then say that $(fg)(x) -e^{2x}$ is monotonic decreasing.

Comment: @EMDB1: What do you mean by "that is what I need to disprove" ? If you've found a counterexample, there isn't a way to disprove that example...

Comment: @Clyton: I found this counterexample now (in the comments in this thread). before i tried to disprove what was said in this question.